# Copy, Paste, Find keyboard shortcuts not working in Windows 10 after a bluescreen and restart. What do I do?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, bsod

Today I had the first ever bluescreen on my laptop since I bought it 2 years ago. The system warned me of some unexpected error and then restarted.

Upon restart, I found everything to be okay, except that the CTRL+C, CTRL+V, CTRL+F shortcuts were no longer working. Strangely, the CTRL+Z and CTRL+X shortcuts are working allright.

I tried the shortcuts in different applications: MS Office 2007, SDL Trados 2013, Google Chrome Browser. The same result, no reaction.

Is there a way to fix this quickly on Windows 10, or is it better to just use a system backup from a week ago? I tried the troubleshooter in the Start-Parameters-Troubleshooting-Keyboard menu but it found no problems.

Comment: I have no idea, but could it have something to do with stuck keys? If a key is physically stuck (maybe shift or alt), or if there is a software error that causes the system to think you're pressing some other key, shortcuts might not function.

Comment: @Cerberus - how did you know that! I just discovered that the custom *calculator* start button on my Microsoft Natural keyboard was stuck! I un-stuck it and viola, everything is working. Post this as an answer, and I'll give you points. Phew! Now there's no need for me to use my week-old backup. I wonder why the laptop was not beeping to signal that a button was stuck.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Good! And done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have something to do with stuck keys? If a key is physically stuck (could even be shift or alt, so you might not see any letters being typed), or if there is a software error that causes the system to think you're pressing some other key, shortcuts might not function.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not your keyboard problem then you must try this methods given below:-

1. Open your command prompt as admin and type in the **sfc/scannow** if it is a registry issue then this scan will fix your issue.
2. Use **chkdsk C: /f /r /x**  command in command prompt and wait for the process until its completion, if any problem in your disk this will it cause windows install on your disk.
3. Disable/Uninstall your third-party antivirus software, you may have installed a cracked software or pirated one which is causing your this issue. remove it and check the issue is if resolved.